# Как настроить обработку исключений в VS?

Tags: visual-studio

Почему-то студия 2012 останавливает программу каждый раз при возникновении исключения, даже если оно обработано пользовательским кодом. Как настроить студию, чтобы она останавливала программу только при необработанных исключениях?

Я думал, что для этого нужно снять флажки User-unhandled, но это невозможно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD1. Да, это debug-сборка. А исключения обрабатываю как обычно:

```
try
{
    throw new Exception();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

UPD2. Странная проблема в самом деле решилась переустановкой. Конечно, есть смысл обсудить истинную причину, но мне этот вопрос уже неинтересен.

UPD3. Странно, не могу закрыть свой вопрос. Так должно быть?

Comment: Звучит странно. Можете пример кода выложить, как вы обрабатываете ошибки?

Comment: Вы запускаете debug сборку?

Comment: Но "проброску" исключений вы не делаете? По идее этот catch должен перепрыгиваться... Очень странно.

Comment: @WalterNuss, почему перепрыгиваться? Код в нём, конечно, есть, но новое исключение в нём не генерируется.

Comment: Я имел ввиду, что VS не должен останавливаться на том месте. Код стоящий там само собой должен обработаться, но исключение не должно показываться. Не видел ещё такого поведения.

Comment: А эта проблема возникает только у вас или у ваших коллег тоже? Может полное удаление VS и вычистка кэша и настроек решила бы проблему. Но это ужасно топорное решение...

Comment: А то же на другой машине работает?

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю снять флажки `Thrown`.